# Several statements about $\mathbb{R}$ with chart defined by $f(x)=x^3$

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I think I managed to show this statements but I am not sure about it. Since this is common problem in differentiable manifolds I was wondering if anybody has (or may write) a solution.

Let $X$ be a copy of the real line $R$ and let $f:X \to R$ be $f(x)=x^3$. Taking $f$ as a chart, this defines a smooth structure on X. Prove or disprove the following statements.

1. X is diffeomorphic to R

My solution: By equivalence of definition of manifold using charts and functional structures we can say that $X$ has functional structure $F(U)= \{l\circ f | l \in C^\infty(f(U))\}$, so by $(R,C^\infty) \to (X,F_x)$ where $x \to x^{1/3}$ we have diffeomorphism becasue for each $g$ (which is equal to $l\circ f$ for some $l$)  in $F_x$ there is $g\circ f^{-1} \in C^\infty$ (which is equal to $l\circ f \circ f^{-1} = l \in C^\infty$ ) Similarly each function in $C^\infty (U)$ we identify with $F(U)$ just from construction ($F(U)= \{l\circ f | l \in C^\infty(f(U))\}$)

2. The identity map $Id: X \to R$ is a diffeomorphism

Solution: No, since function $k$ sending $x$ to $x$ is in $(R,C^\infty)$ but $k\circ Id^{-1}=k$ is not in $F(R)$ because $k\circ x^{1/3} = x^{1/3} \not\in (R,C^\infty)$

3. $f$ together with identity map comprise an atlas

Solution: $f^{-1} \not\in C^\infty$ thus we don't have proper change of coordinates.

4. The last question I will post later

I hope you understand my proofs and have yours! Thank you!

You can find all of these in Bredon's Topology and Geomerty p.76

Comment: These are all fine. When you're going to post something you should try to have the post complete when you post it (eg, don't add questions later).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My comments are below (all of your solutions are correct, so what is below is not much more than paraphrasing what you have said in my own words):

1. The function $\phi: X\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by the rule $\phi(x) = x^{1/3}$ is smooth (as a map between smooth manifolds).
2. The "identity map" $X\to \mathbb{R}$ is given by $\psi(x) = x^3$ in local coordinates (i.e., $\psi: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$); although $\psi$ is smooth, $\psi^{-1}$ is not smooth (at $0$) so the identity map is not a diffeomorphism $X\to \mathbb{R}$.
3. Yes, as you say, the transition map (corresponding to $f$ and the identity) is given by $\psi$ (see 2. above) in local coordinates, which is not a diffeomorphism for the reason explained (also in 2.).

Hope this helps!

(As a supplementary remark, it is worth pointing out that a 1-manifold admits a unique smooth structure up to diffeomorphism; so the classification of topological 1-manifolds is equivalent to the classification of smooth 1-manifolds. In fact, this statement is true for $n$-manifolds where $n\leq 3$, and fails for $n=4$ (where deep phenomena occur which in a sense are still poorly understood). For example, $\mathbb{R}^4$ admits uncountably many smooth structures (the only $n$ for which $\mathbb{R}^n$ admits an exotic (i.e., nonstandard) smooth structure is $n=4$), and it is the open (smooth) Poincaré conjecture as to whether or not $\mathbb{S}^4$ admits any exotic smooth structures.)

Comment: Where can I find other ways to prove that maps between manifolds are diffeomorphism?  By this I mean that I know how to do this with the definition of functional structures but you did it without even referring to this definition.

Comment: Hi @Vadim, I used the "atlas definition" for smooth manifolds and smooth maps, which is equivalent to the "functional structure definition". I like the functional structure definition a lot, perhaps more than the atlas definition, but I think the atlas definition is the most commonly used definition (e.g., in books on differential geometry). For example, it is probably discussed in Wikipedia.

Comment: Thank you. My encounter with smooth manifolds is only Bredon's book and he doesn't use much of the atlas defenition. I will read some more material to get familiar with the "atlas" one.

Comment: Btw, I think that I and you both made mistakes by taking different maps. In first I did x to x^3 but should take x to x^1/3, and you in the first should take phi(x)=x^3. Also, the same thing for your second argument because in the local coordinates identity map sends x to x^(1/3). x=Id(x)=Id(f^(-1)•f(x))=id(f^(-1))(x^3)=phi(x^3) in local coordinates.

Comment: Do you agree? Sorry for notation, I was writing from the iPhone

Comment: Hi @Vadim, thanks for your comment. I guess this is simply a notational point depending on how you define a "chart". In my answer, I think of the chart $f(x) = x^3$ for $X$ as being a map $\mathbb{R}\to X$; with this definition, verifying that $\phi:X\to \mathbb{R}$ is a diffeomorphism is tantamount to verifying that $\phi\circ f: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is a diffeomorphism; of course, this is so because the composition is the identity map of $\mathbb{R}$ ...

Comment: @ Amitesh I agree. Thanks again

Comment: ... If you think of a chart as being a map in the other direction (i.e., $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ is defined by the rule $f(x)=x^3$), then $\phi(x)= x^3$ would be correct (because now verifying that $\phi:X\to\mathbb{R}$ is a diffeomorphism is tantamount to verifying that $\phi\circ f^{-1}:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a diffeomorphism, which is now so since this is the identity (but would be $x^{1/9}$ with $\phi(x) = x^{1/3}$). So, I don't think this is a mistake (for either of us).